# Delphi 7 - Charset REST JSON

Tags: json, rest, delphi, character-encoding, indy

With Delphi 7 and Indy 9.00.10 I'm using a REST API with JSON. 
I create a GET request with the TidHTTP component like this.

```
IdHTTP1.HandleRedirects := True;
IdHTTP1.ReadTimeout     := 5000;
IdHTTP1.Request.Accept  := 'application/json';
IdHTTP1.Request.AcceptCharSet  := 'UTF-8';
IdHTTP1.Request.AcceptLanguage := 'sv';
IdHTTP1.Request.ContentType    := 'application/json';
Memo1.Text := IdHTTP1.Get('http://api.arbetsformedlingen.se/af/v0/platsannonser/7088149');
```

I have tried several charset but can not correct the Swedish characters like å,ä,ö in the response.

- å becomes Ã¥
- ä becomes Ã¤
- ö becomes Ã¶

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Reply starts with `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>`.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info. Now when I try it, I can clearly see the ä, ö and å characters correctly in the memo, as e.g. " konsult om du söker en värld av"

Comment: Strange, i still get this [link](http://imgur.com/KbMADMb)
Im jusing Delphi 7 with Indy 9.00.10

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Delphi 7 `System` unit there's an `UTF8ToAnsi()` function. Use like this:

```
  Memo1.Text := UTF8ToAnsi(IdHTTP1.Get('http://api.arbetsformedlingen.se/af/v0/platsannonser/7088149'));
```

The result is correct in Delphi 7.

Comment: You have been very helpful in this topic. Thanks to you we have come to the conclusion that it is Delphi 7 that does not support Unicode. And to convert UTF-8 to ANSI today in year 2017 just feels completely wrong but in this case it will be the right way to go. Otherwise, I use UTF-8 everywhere, always!

Comment: Delphi 7 does not have full Unicode support. It's default string type uses ANSI encoding. If you want full Unicode support in 2017 then upgrade to new version. Delphi 7 is more than 15 years old.

Comment: @TomBrunberg sorry, my words were meant for OP.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using Delphi 7. And asking questions about it. And answering them, But when one uses such old version it must accept its downsides. Complaining that Delphi 7 uses ANSI is kind of pointless.

Comment: In Delphi 7, you can use `UTF8Decode()` to decode a UTF-8 encoded `AnsiString` to a Unicode `WideString`. But in this case, it would be better to use the `TStream` version of `TIdHTTP.Get()` instead so you can then pass the raw XML data as-is to your chosen XML parser. Don't parse XML as an Ansi string. Let the XML engine parse it for you using the XML's actual charset.